# npm run gulp primordials not defined

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-run

I'm trying to run `npm run gulp` and I'm coming up with this primordials is not defined error (I have also added the npm-shrinkwrap.json file as suggested which gets updated after running npm install but it doesn't fix my primordials is not define error):

```
> gulp-tutorial@1.0.0 gulp
> gulp

fs.js:47
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theming-main/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theming-main/node_modules/natives/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theming-main/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

Node.js v17.0.1
```

Any suggestions  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the versions not matching up. I also had 2 NodeJS installation paths and that was throwing things off.

I uninstalled them all, started from the beginning and used brew to reinstall.

Then checked that the versions were all compatible.

I also had to install node-sass and referred to this compatibility table to get the correct version - https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Now its working and I can get on developing :) As of today Im running Node v17.0.1 Npm v8.1.0 Gulp cli v2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Primordials are used by Node.js internal modules and are not accessible to end user scripts. (That's their entire point for existing. Otherwise, you could modify `Object.prototype` and end up affecting Node.js internals, causing weird crashes and things like that.)

The module that is giving you this error is the `natives` module. The [page for the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natives) says:

> This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.

Sounds like it's at that point where it's broken. Use `npm ls natives` to find out what's using it. (You might need to be in the `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theming-main` directory when you run the command.) From there, you can try to figure out how to get rid of it.

Another possibility would be to try downgrading to an earlier version of Node.js to see if it works with that version.

Comment: Thanks for your help, for me it was a problem with the versions not matching up. I also had 2 NodeJS installation paths and that was throwing things off. So I uninstalled them all, started from the beginning and used brew to reinstall. Then checked that the versions were all compatible. Now its working and I can get on developing :) As of today Im running Node v17.0.1 Npm v8.1.0 Gulp cli v2.3.0